# Last GPO refresh time

Tags: wmi, wmic, wmi-query, gpo

Which WMI class contains the information of last gpo application time in that computer? I checked RSOP_Session's CreationTime property, but it is showing some time in 2013 year (10 years old time). I checked in another machine, that is also showing time as 20130822145022.000000+000

Kindly assist me in getting the required info (Not interested in using gpresult command to get the last time the gpos applied on a computer).